# Question regarding validity of $\partial A = \partial(\mathbb{X} \verb!\!A) $ for a Hausdorff topology

Tags: general-topology, numerical-methods

Let $\mathbb{X}$ be a topological Hausdorff space. Then for $A \subset \mathbb{X}$ it holds that $\partial A = \partial(\mathbb{X} \verb!\!A) $, where $\partial A$ i.e. is the set of boundary points for $A$.

The material I have claims that this equality holds. However, I have a difficult time validating it. Here's how my material goes about with the proof:

$x \in \partial A \implies \forall N \in V(x) : N \cap(\mathbb{X} \verb!\!A) \neq \emptyset \implies x \in \partial (\mathbb{X} \verb!\! A)$

Where $V(x)$ is the set of all neighborhoods of $x$. I can perhaps see how $\exists x \in \partial A :x \in \partial (\mathbb{X} \verb!\! A) $ would make sense, but a straight up equality?

I.e., let's say that $\mathbb{X}$ is a topology on a space in the interval $[1,10]$. Then let's say $A=\verb!{! x : x \in [4,6] \verb!}!$. This would give us:

$(\mathbb{X} \verb!\!A) = \verb!{! x : x \in [1,4) \cup(6,10] \verb!}! $

However, $\partial A = \partial(\mathbb{X} \verb!\!A) $ would not hold since $\partial A = \verb!{! 4,6 \verb!}!$ and $\partial(\mathbb{X} \verb!\!A) =\verb!{! 1,4,6,10 \verb!}!$.

Any help is appreciated. Also, please don't hesitate to correct me if I have done something incorrect.

Best regards,

kasp9201.

Comment: $\partial A = \{4,6\}  =\partial(X\setminus A)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition (well, one of the equivalent definitions), the boundary of $A$ is the set of points $x$ in $X$ such that every neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $A$ as well as its complement. This definition is clearly symmetrical with respect to $A$ vs $X\setminus A$, and you need no separation axioms for that.

In your example, $1$ and $10$ are *not* on the boundary of $X\setminus A$: a neighbourhood of $1$ (in $X$), for example, is a set containing an interval of the form $[1,b)$ for some $b<10$. For example, $[1,3)$ is a neighbourhood of $1$ disjoint from $A$ (which is the complement of $X\setminus A$).

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. I can see that your explanation actually fits with my definitions, and that I should just have been more careful. Thanks a bunch!